Convert List<Task<T>>> to List<T>
I have this variable that should project and return a list of AttachmentRequestModel as follows :
 var mappedAttachments = recordAction
     .PPAttachments
     .Select(async x => new AttachmentRequestModel()
     {
         AttachmentId = 1,
         AttachmentContent = await GetReportAttachContentAsync(1),
         AttachmentName = "name",
         AttachmentType = 1
     })
     .ToList();

mappedAttachments variable return a List<Task<AttachmentRequestModel>> how can I change it to return List<AttachmentRequestModel> instead?
Edit : I changed the code, looping through each task in the list and await for it as bellow :
var anotherAttachList = new List<AttachmentRequestModel>();
foreach (var attachTask in mappedAttachments)
    anotherAttachList.Add(await attachTask);

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

the problem with your edited code is that it is not trying to do more than one task at a time.

Try using Task.WhenAll,
 var mappedAttachments = (await Task.WhenAll(recordAction.PPAttachments
     .Select(async x => new AttachmentRequestModel()
     {
         AttachmentId = 1,
         AttachmentContent = await GetReportAttachContentAsync(1),
         AttachmentName = "name",
         AttachmentType = 1
     })))
     .ToList();

